# Calculating the CGAffineTransform matrix after rotating the superview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

This one is tricky!

I have view A and view B which is a subview of view A. The frames of both views are constant.

I rotate view A by changing the transform-matrix:

```
viewA.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

Now I want to adjust the transform-matrix of view B, so that the visual position and rotation stays the same i.e. B must not move/rotate while changing the rotation angle of A.

Obviously I need to rotate view B in the opposite direction, but that is not enough.

I tried this but B still wobbles around:

```
viewB.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle), viewA.bounds.size.width, viewA.bounds.size.height);
```

Maybe the correct matrix also depends on the frame of viewB ... maybe I need to use sine and cosine ... ?

I know, I could simply make B a sibling view of A, but I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this and let me know pls

```
viewB.transform=CGAffineTransformInvert(viewA.transform)
```

Comment: This is the same as `viewB.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle)` because `CGAffineTransformInvert (CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle))` and `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle)` are exactly the same. As I mentioned, rotating is not enough.

Comment: i'm not understand ur answer, what do u want to achieve finally.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that popped into my head.

First, why not remove view B from view A and attach it to the superview of view A (even if its just for the rotation sequence)? It will be visually identical.

My other thought is wrapping the animations in a CATransaction to keep the animations in sync.

I would still recommend not keeping view B on view A and having to run two animations, instead of just one. Is the reason you're keeping view B inside view A, because its clipping based on it's bounds?

This is with layers, but it works the same with views:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction flush];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/4, 0, 0, 1);
outerLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(outerLayer.transform, transform);
innerLayer.transform = CATransform3DInvert(outerLayer.transform);
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with animations! I don't say that I animate the transform-property. I know I can keep B outside of A, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: You're instantaneously applying a transform to a view? Wouldn't that confuse a user? If the view transitions from one position to the next with a fluid motion, that is indeed an animation. Both suggestions would prevent your view from being screwed up with transforms.

Comment: Why don't you "want to" make view B a sibling view, if you're not willing to try other animation styles. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Okay, in the meantime I solved it by creating a new view and adding A and B as subviews. But I'm still interested in how I would calculate the transform matrix when B is subview of A. And I'll only accept answers that give me the correct formula.

Comment: Are you kidding me? My CATransaction keeps the view animations in sync. How is that not the answer? Did you even try it? I just made an example project of exactly your problem and it works just fine. Try the answers before rejecting them.

Comment: No, I'm serious. Even though I solved my problem in the real world application using a workaround I still want to know the formula for the matrix when B is subview of A. Take it as a hypothetical question. Performance doesn't matter. Can you give me sample code for your CATransaction?

Comment: You were right in what you did. The CATransaction just lines the two animations up so that they don't wobble or shift inconsistently. You just have to 'begin' a CATransaction and set the animation duration (you don't HAVE to, but its a good idea), write out your transforms and then commit the CATransaction. You can also set timing functions.